# Querying datetime object in django doesn't work because of time zone

Tags: python, django, django-timezone

I'm facing the issue of wrong query result due to timezone issue. I've read several answers, but most of them suggest `USE_TZ = False`. But we can't do that because of several dependencies on time zone.

```
blog = Post.objects.filter(date_posted__year=2019, date_posted__month=11)
blog[0]
```

> Post: asfd random new india safasfd adf hey

```
blog[0].date_posted
```

> datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 26, 20, 33, 58, tzinfo=)

```
blog[0].date_posted.day
```

> 26

When I query on day 26 it throws error:

`Post.objects.get(date_posted__year=2019, date_posted__month=11, date_posted__day=26, slug=blog[0].slug)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/insol/webD/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/insol/webD/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
Blog.models.Post.DoesNotExist: Post matching query does not exist.
```

But it works on day 27.

```
Post.objects.get(date_posted__year=2019, date_posted__month=11, date_posted__day=27, slug=blog[0].slug)
```

Output:

```
<Post: asfd random new india safasfd adf hey>
```

---

I tried :

```
Post.objects.get(date_posted=datetime.date(2019, 11, 27))
```

throws:

```
/home/insol/webD/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1365: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Post.date_posted received a naive datetime (2019-11-27 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

Using this :

```
Post.objects.get(date_posted=datetime(2019, 11, 26, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')))
```

throws :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/insol/webD/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/insol/webD/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
Blog.models.Post.DoesNotExist: Post matching query does not exist.
```

Is there a way through which I can solve this issue?

Comment: But this is a weird thing to do. Why don't you do `Post.objects.get(date_posted=datetime.date(2019, 11, 26))`?

Comment: I've edited the question. Its working in DetailView but not in function based view.

Comment: which database are you using? what is the value of `date_posted` inside the database?